# Cant open large size PDF files in IE11

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-11

I have a program which produces reports in PDF. Most of the reports are under 200K in size. On occasion the report has more data and can be a lot higher in size (up to 1MB). The reports will download with no issues if under a certain size (I do not know what the limit is at this point) and then error out if they exceed that size.
I have been unable to identify a fix for this issue, but the workaround is to install and have the users run the reports on Firefox.
Is there a setting or something in Internet Explorer 11 which will allow larger PDF files to download and display?

Comment: what tool or code are you using to generate your PDF's?

Comment: Have you been able to identify what the actual error is? What do you see in the F12 dev tools?

Comment: The tool is flash report which takes excel spreadsheet data and converts it to a pdf - very simple and has worked for years. IE, 9, 10 and now it wont work in 11.

Comment: With what viewer? Certainly IE 9 or 10 were not viewing the PDF with the browser, they were using a plugin. Is IE 11 using that same plugin (i.e. Adobe or are you using now Edge and the native PDF viewing). And if you are using the Adobe Plugin for all environments, possibly the problem is with the plugin and not the browser. Firefox is not using Reader to view the PDF.